# Images on a page are not aligning

Tags: html, css, image

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but my images aren't  being displayed side by side on the screen? I am pretty new to CSS by the way. Ideally, I would like the images to be displayed like so - [bensilvertown.com](http://bensilvertown.com)

Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="work images">
<div>
    <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="/Users/mac/Documents/PICTURES/cursor.png" />
    <p>This is image 1</p>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="/Users/mac/Documents/PICTURES/MIKE\ BRODIE.jpg" />
    <p>This is image 2</p>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    html{
       background-color: #000000
   }

    html,body{
       color: #fff;
       font-family:
       font-weight:
    }

   /*align images side by side!*/
   div{
     float:left;
     margin-right:5px;
    }

    div > img{
      height:200px;
      width:200px;
    }

    p{
      text-align:center;
    }
```

Comment: Your `<a>` tags are not closed.

Comment: @Kangouroops Thanks, I done that but still the problem is there. I've got a feeling its got something to do with how I'm saving my code on my laptop. I can see the changes correct on sbin's live output, but the .html on my laptop doesn't look updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert `display:inline;` property inside the `div`

Obs1: I've changed your images paths to validate better your code.
Obs2: Your forgot to close your tag `<a>` before img 
Obs3: They will be side by side only if you have enough resolution.

https://jsfiddle.net/2ke6huxs/

Comment: i clicked the link, image 2 is below image 1. I need them side by side

Comment: They are side by side if your screen is wide enough.
@Yuri > Why do you use `display:inline` ? it's already floating, no ?

Comment: @Kangouroops Thanks for the addition, Ive guessed it was implicit. already made my edition.

Comment: You are welcome.

And I would suggest Jordan to not use the `div` selector, but to give a class to div parent of the img.

Comment: Yeah, definitely. It helps him to give more specificity to his div and make it more readable when the code gets bigger.

Comment: @Kangouroops thank for the help. Can you give an example of giving a class to the div parent of img please?

Comment: @YuriRamos the images are left, I tried to centre them but that didn't work?

Comment: Remove the float from the `div`  and add to `.work` width:100%;text-align:center;

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are missing to close  and not link right for second image `<img src="/Users/mac/Documents/PICTURES/MIKE/BRODIE.jpg" />` you can seen difference.

Try this to add float left on image:

`div > img{
      height:200px;
      width:200px;
      float:left;
    }`

Comment: I need the images in the centre, not left. How can this be done?

Comment: then need to make so  
`div > img{
      height:200px;
      width:200px;
      display:inline-block;
    }`

Comment: but also remember that your  `div{
     float:left;
     margin-right:5px;
    }` need to have some width larger then image width and text-align:center; and in box will been image centered.